# Caliburn Micro cancel window close from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

When the user clicks the close button of a Window, is it possible to cancel the close from the ViewModel or do I have to resort to code behind?

From what I can tell, CanClose or TryClose doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may have already tried this but I've just created a quick test, deriving a view model from `Screen` and overriding CanClose.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
    {
        //if(some logic...)
        callback(false); // will cancel close
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Guess I didn't understand how to use CanClose.